# Declaring a class with a custom constructor in another class

Tags: c++

I have a class whose only constructor accepts an integer, and I would like to use it in another class without making it a pointer and using new/delete.

Is this even possible?

Relevant parts of first class:

```
class A
{
  private:
  int size; 
  char *c;

  public:
  A(int i)
  {
    size = i;
    c = new char[i];
  }
  ~A() { delete[] c; }
}
```

And I want to use it in an example class B as follows:

```
class B
{
  private:
  A a(7); // Declaration attempt #1
  A b; //Declaration attempt #2
  A *c; //This is what I'll do if I have no other choice.

  public:
  B()
  {
    b = A(7); //Declaration attempt #2
    c = new A(7);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you compiled the code? what does the compiler say? You missed `;` for class after `}`

Comment: #1 works in C++11 and #2 works anywhere. Just please never use `new` unless you really have a really good reason to.

Comment: @taocp: I typed these theoretical classes out to narrow down the point of what I was asking without pasting a 60 line class, so I'm surprised I only got a ; wrong!

Comment: @chris: I am trying to avoid using `new`. #2 doesn't work since I haven't defined a A() constructor...I want to force an integer to be passed in to initialize the private array. Upgrading gcc to support C++11 seems like a lot of work though...

Comment: Upgrading GCC really isn't much work, at least not how I've ever done it. And #2 does work, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-class initialization of an object using `()` is not possible because it gets interpreted as a function declaration. You can use the member-initializer list to do this instead:

```
class B
{
    A a;

    public:
        B() : a(7)
    //      ^^^^^^
        {}
};
```

This would also work with assignment inside the constructor but the member-initializer list is recommended because *initializes* instead of assigns.

In C++11 you can use uniform-initialization:

```
class B
{
    A a{7};                                                                    /*
    ^^^^^^^                                                                    */

    public:
        B() = default;
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need! Thank you!

Now...say I needed to declare `A a1, a2;`, how would I go about initializing both `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: @SVC You would use both in the mem-initializer list: `B() : a1(5), a2(6) {}` or in C++11: `A a1{5}, a2{6};`